# Insert date in a empty column of a file delimited with "|"

Tags: shell

I have a file with four columns delimited by "|" as below

```
23414|test doc for me||
32322|test doc for you|2004_12_03|
13454|test doc for all||2010_11_01
```

i am trying to insert current system date to the empty column's so that output should looks like as

```
23414|test doc for me|2018_04_03|2018_04_03
32322|test doc for you|2004_12_03|2018_04_03
13454|test doc for all|2018_04_03|2010_11_01
```

below is the code which i am tried

```
for file in `ls -rlt Added_to_* | awk '{print $9}'`
do
now="$(date +'%Y/%m/%d')"
echo "Running for: $file"
awk -F'|' -v curr="$now" '{ 
if( $3=="" || $4=="" ){ 
     if ( $3=="" ) { print "$curr"}
     if ( $4=="" ) { print "$curr"}
}else  
     do_something ; 
}' $file 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

@hemu:@try:

```
awk -F"|" -v DATE=$(date +%Y"-"%m"-"%d) '!$3{$3=DATE} !$4{$4=DATE} 1' OFS="|"  Input_file
```

Simply mentioning the field separator as | then creating a awk's variable which has a shell date command which gives values in YYYY-MM-DD formats. Then in awk I am checking if 3rd or 4th field is empty then making their values as DATE's value then mentioning 1 here will print the current(newly formed with value of $4 or $3 if they have been assigned with new values) line.